# CHAdeMO to Type 2 connector for charging EV cars

Tags: electricity, cars, electric-vehicles

I'd like to refresh and potentially update my knowledge.

Is there anything like CHAdeMO charging cable to Type 2 car plug connector? or any other solution that would allow me to charge my Type 2 car from CHAdeMO cable / charging station? Or no such thing exists.

My knowledge gained so far says that there isn't anything like that and that designing such thing isn't possible due to wide differences in CHAdeMO and Type 2 interfaces up to the level of different request-answer timeouts, voltages, logic and software behind.

I understand that CHAdeMO technology / protocol / standard is being phased-out worldwide, but here were I live (Poland) there is a serious number of (roughly ever used) public EV chargers with CHAdeMO cable. And I'd like to have an additional option / my inset into sustainable living by charging my Type 2 car with CHAdeMO cable in situation when other solutions (like using Type 2 cable / plug or CCS cable) are not available. Instead of circling additional kilometres to the next charging station (only to figure out that once available socket is now taken and I have to circle back to the first station).

From my perspective this is not a theoretical question. I had such situation three times only this weekend, so I'd like to find a solution to avoid it in the future..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's nearly impossible, or at least so impractical it won't happen.

CHAdeMO is DC fast charging.

Type 2 is AC charging.

In theory, you could create a 11 kW inverter converting CHAdeMO DC signal into three-phase AC, but the cable to do that would be terribly heavy. I'd say the block in the middle of the cable would weigh approximately 20 kg to do that. It would also cost ~2000 EUR / USD / GBP.

Theoretically if 3.6 kW is enough for you, you might have only 7 kg block in the middle of the cable, but as far as I know, CHAdeMO is used only in public charging stations. With 3.6 kW, it would take approximately 20 hours to fill a typical electric vehicle battery in a public charging station.

CHAdeMO doesn't have AC at all. So no possible to avoid the need of the heavy inverter. Type 2 on the other hand doesn't have DC at all so you can't direct-feed DC from CHAdeMO into Type 2.

Comment: CHAdeMO to CCS (although DC to DC so easier) seems to be very impractical as well: https://www.speakev.com/threads/is-it-technically-possible-to-have-an-adaptor-between-ccs-and-chademo.129218/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer an a comment which partially or practically answers [my other question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/12299/14308). However, your linked forum says: "_An adapter in the CCS(car) to CHAdeMO(charger) direction is significantly easier than one in the other direction - and Tesla's adapter is in most respects equivalent to that easier case_". Which (if I am getting it correctly) would make CHAdeMO charger / cable to CCS port possible (or even existing -- Tesla?). If you can, please answer my other question. Thank you.