# A converter from CHAdeMO cable to CCS connector for charging EV cars

Tags: electricity, cars, electric-vehicles

A very similar question to [this one](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/12299/14308). Is there any solution available to use CHAdeMO charging cable to power EV car equipped with CCS socket?

My knowledge gained so far says that there isn't anything like that because there are too wide differences in CHAdeMO and CCS interfaces (up to the level of different request-answer timeouts, voltages, logic, software behind, etc.).

I understand that CHAdeMO technology / protocol / standard is being phased-out worldwide, but here were I live (Poland) there is a vast number of public EV chargers with (roughly never used) CHAdeMO cables.

I'd like to have an additional option (my inset into sustainable living) of charging my CCS car with CHAdeMO cable in situation when options (Type 2 cable or plug or CCS cable) are not available. Instead of circling additional kilometres to the next charging station.

I don't know pretty much nothing about Tesla, but I saw Tesla driver powering its car from CHAdeMO (or maybe it was CSS?) cable using some kind of converter or inverter plugged between EV charging station's cable and Tesla's socket. I'd like to know, if similar option exists, if we have CCS instead of Tesla socket?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that an exactly the same solution / converter as asked is available in the market: **Tesla Chademo Adapter EU 1036391-10-D**. [Here is](https://allegro.pl/oferta/tesla-chademo-adapter-eu-1036391-10-d-11414853743) a link to a Polish shop offer for one of them:

[image]

If I am getting the above picture correctly, this is exactly what I've been asking for: Put a CHAdeMO cable from a charger into this adapter and put the adapter into CCS socket in an electric car.

The price (2499 PLN / 510 USD / 530 EUR) is a killer for me. I'd rather go to the second or third charger, if previous one has only CHAdeMO cable available rather than spending that amount of money for such an adapter.

Comment: That is not a CCS plug. It's a Type 2 plug, which forms *part* of a CCS connector.... So I guess in a sense this might help the OP, but only if they want to charge their car very slowly.

Comment: Type 2 accepts up to 44 kW (at least I have stations with such designation in my country) and CHAdeMO _gives out_ 50 kW at max. I'd say difference is minimal. People are charging their EVs using sockets as "small" as 5,6 kW or 11 kW, so I'd strongly doubt if charging a car with 44 kW still mandates as _very_ slowly.

Comment: Type 2 might support up to 44kW (that surprises me, I thought it was 22, but I might be wrong) - but most cars don't. Renault Zoes will charge at 22kW on type 2, but most others will only do 7 or 11 kW. Also, since (I think?) CHAdeMO is a DC system with most of the hardware in the "shore station", and type 2 charging is AC with the charger in the car, I don't actually know if this will work at all for non-Teslas...

Comment: I am also surprised with the possibility of charging AC 44 kW through Type 2. That's why I did mention a stickers on my chargers around and in-app information. My car also limits charging to 22 kW at most. I don't own any Tesla and don't know nothing about it. Could it be that it charges DC through Type 2? That would explain connecting pure-DC charger (CHAdeMO) to the AC socket (Type 2) through this extension.

Comment: doing a little googling around this, it appears that Tesla connectors are different in the US vs EU, which makes everything confusing. But it looks as though in the EU, where they use Type 2 for their own charging stations, they do put DC through them at up to 43 kW.
Some (very little) info at https://www.zap-map.com/charge-points/tesla-model-s-charging-guide/